# How to change the thumbnail interval with ElasticTranscoder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-transcoder

How do you change the interval between thumbnails created (it seems to default to one thumbnail per minute).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are creating a preset, there is an option within the Thumbnails section down the bottom for "Interval". This is the number of seconds between thumbnails. Then, when you submit an encoding job, you specify the naming convention for the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Also by changing the preset thumbnail interval by copying the preset 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/changing-presets.html